# TrayIcon com console oculto

Tags: java, console, system-tray

Estou com um programa em `java`, sem interface gráfica, apenas console. Os únicos comandos de saída são `System.out.println()`.
Implementei-o de forma que o programa tivesse um trayicon. O problema é que quero apenas o trayicon ativo quando executar e atualmente está executando tray+console.

Tentei, mas sem sucesso:

```
Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
                SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
                Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\logo.png");
                final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
                MenuItem aboutItem = new MenuItem("WS");
                Menu displayMenu = new Menu("Hora de Inicio");                   
                MenuItem hora = new MenuItem(tempo);
                popup.add(aboutItem);
                popup.addSeparator();
                popup.add(displayMenu);
                displayMenu.add(hora);
                TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "WebService", popup);
                trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true); 
                try {
                  tray.add(trayIcon);
                  this.setVisible(false);
                  trayIcon.displayMessage("Aviso!", "Programa continua em execução...", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                } catch (AWTException e) {
                  System.err.println("Não pode adicionar a tray");
                }
              } else {
                System.err.println("Tray indisponível");
              }
            }
          };
          EventQueue.invokeLater(runner);
```

Como executo essa aplicação:

Após realizar o build no NetBeans simplesmente uso o "`java -jar ws.jar`" ou então uso o Launch4j, crio um `exe` e double click. Ele exibe uma janela preta(padrão da aplicação+windows

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu gostaria seria de ocultar a tela acima e deixar apenas via tray(não correr o risco de alguém fechar o console e parar a aplicação)

Comment: Por favor, adicione **[mcve]** do seu código, para que seja possivel reproduzir o problema.

Comment: @diegofm o exemplo do código utilizado para tentar esconder a janela está na pergunta.

Comment: Mas não é suficiente para testar. O problema pode nem estar ai.

Comment: Alterado @diegofm

Comment: Onde o tal console é chamado? Sinceramente não vejo problema no código e nem estou entendendo o problema relatado.

Comment: @diegofm console seria a saida padrão com qualquer System.out.println(). Por exemplo System.out.println("ola mundo") irá imprimir "ola mundo" no console do windows se executar um java -jar programa.jar

Comment: @diegofm o problema é que o this.setVisible(false) não está funcionando. O console continua visível.

Comment: Tente rodar sua classe com o `javaw`, depois disso você pode fechar o console.

Comment: Se não tem Um container ou componente swing/awt, setvisible não vai funcionar.

Comment: @Math tentarei e retorno

Comment: @Math qual a diferença entre os dois? Usando javaw o resultado esperado foi alcançado.

Comment: @LucasTorres a diferença é que o comando `javaw`  não está associado com uma janela de console, portanto depois que você rodar o comando a sua aplicação em java rodará independentemente da janela, já no caso do `java` a sua janela ficará esperando a sua aplicação encerrar para que ela possa prosseguir com novos comandos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo que vi você não está mais tendo problemas com o TrayIcon, apenas deseja que uma janela de console do windows não fique aguardando o fim da execução do seu programa. Para resolver esse empecilho você pode usar o comando `javaw` para chamar a sua classe, ao invés do comando `java`.

Da [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html):

> The javaw command is identical to java, except that with javaw there is no associated console window. Use javaw when you do not want a command prompt window to appear. The javaw launcher will, however, display a dialog box with error information if a launch fails.

Em tradução livre:

> O comando javaw é idêntico ao comando java, exceto que com o javaw não existe uma janela de console associada. Use javaw quando você não quiser que uma janela de comando apareça. O launcher javaw vai, entretanto, exicibir uma janela de diálogo com informações de erros se a chamada falhar.